# Что лучше и правильнее использовать в качестве первичного ключа: автоинкремент или UUID?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, postgresql

Или же существенного различия между ними нет? Многие пишут, что автоинкремент - это плохой выбор и в качестве первичного ключа лучше использовать UUID. Однако весомых аргументов в пользу данного утверждения я так и не нашел. Проблемы со слиянием двух таблиц с автоинкрементом, перебор сущностей и т.д. - это лишь частные случаи, и далеко не всегда они являются критичными.

Comment: Выбор осуществляется по конкретной задаче. Если не нужно сливать таблицы и защищаться от перебора сущностей, то и автоинкремент прекрасно справится со своей задачей.

Comment: Если Вы не можете чётко обосновать для себя, чем именно AI плох в Вашем конкретном случае по сравнению с UUID настолько, что следует выбрать UUID - однозначно выбирайте AI.

Comment: А еще зависит от БД и способа генерации uuid. Как то меня попросили посмотреть, почему тормозит одна система. Дано: Mysql InnoDB; 150 млн записей; ключ - uuid, назначаемый несколькими разными способами и обычно как хеш. `select count(1)` за один день (100k-1kk записей) работал минут 5, при том что день пишется вроде как подряд. Только вот innoDB сортирует по ключу и данные оказываются размазанными по всему объему файла в 200 Гб. В итоге был введен bigint id (правда автоинкремент из за особенностей работы был неприменим, пришлось делать свой генератор). Скорость count() за день - 3-4 сек

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Коллеги уже привели аргументы в пользу автоинкремента.  Вот некоторые
аргументы в пользу *UUID*:

- *Сокрытие информации.*  Тут всё просто.  Если кто-то видит, что
  в вашей системе есть, например, пользователь с *ID* 42, он может
  понять, что в системе как минимум 42 пользователя, а также что в системе
  скорее всего есть пользователи 41 и 43.  По *UUID* он мало что
  поймёт.
- *Источник идентификатора.*  *UUID* может быть сгенерирован
  как на стороне приложения, так и на стороне СУБД.  В случае
  с автоинкрементом, только на стороне СУБД.
- *Шардирование.*  Во многом выходит из предыдущего пункта.
  Держать распределённый счётчик часто тяжело, и с увеличением числа узлов
  будет страдать быстродействие системы.  С *UUID* такой проблемы нет.

Коллеги упоминали быстродействие, но тут стоит отметить, что многие
СУБД имеют специальный тип `UUID`, который как правило
занимает 128 бит.  На большинстве современных машин это два
слова, в то время как обычный `BIGINT` или
`INTEGER` — одно.  Реальный «ущерб» от
*UUID* надо смотреть на конкретной машине и для конкретных
данных.

Comment: Сокрытие: id можно зашифровать при передаче клиенту. Источник: автоинкремент может быть внешним (но конечно либо строго внешний либо строго БД). Шардирование: не вижу никакой разницы откуда взять несколько бит данных для выбора ноды. По поводу "ущерба" в конкретном случае см. коммент под вопросом

Answer (score 0):

Если нет задачи задания глобально уникального ключа, то лучше использовать автоинкремент, поскольку работа с ним намного быстрее (поле небольшое, индексация проходит на ура, есть порядок записей - соответственно соединять, объединять по данным полям быстрее).

обновлено.
Почитайте [Первичный ключ – GUID или автоинкремент?](https://habr.com/ru/post/265437/)

Comment: У uuid также есть порядок

Comment: Да очень большой и в не той последовательности что был введен

Comment: Обоснуйте пожалуйста баши утверждения, например, ссылками на документацию.

Comment: @AzizUmarov ууид имеет в старших байтах последовательность на основе метки времени

Comment: почитайте тут https://habr.com/ru/post/265437/

Comment: @eri UUIDv4 не имеет метки времени, например